# d3: line chart x-axis -- How to have tickValues with same padding?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3.js and trying to build a line chart. It has specific tickValues which should be shown. But I want to show the tickValues with the same padding between each other, even if they differ in their increasement.

Here my values:

```
var data = [{
        "db": "10",
        "freq": "125"
    }, {
        "db": "15",
        "freq": "250"
    }, {
        "db": "40",
        "freq": "500"
    }, {
        "db": "30",
        "freq": "1000"
    }, {
        "db": "20",
        "freq": "2000"
    }, {
        "db": "30",
        "freq": "4000"
    }, {
        "db": "10",
        "freq": "8000"
    }];
```

This is the scale of the x-axis:

```
 var x = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([0, width]);

 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .tickFormat(d3.format('0f'))
            .tickValues([125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000])
            .orient("bottom");
```

This is the output in real:

[image]

And this how it should be:

[image]

(Please ignore the color and styling, it only matters the padding)

I have tried several scaling types, ticks, etc, nothing works. Without the scaling property of course no tickValues are shown.

My question: How can I turn of this scaling between the tickValues and get the same padding between each tick, even if the values don't increase linear?

Comment: have you looked at [ordinal scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal)?

Comment: Nope, didn't see that, thanks. Can you tell me which settings domain and range should have with the ordinal scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Cool Blue I got the answer.

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(["125", "250", "500", "1000", "2000", "4000", "8000"])
            .rangePoints([0, width]);
x.range();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");
```

If you need to start from a different point than 0, like in this example, you need to use rangePoints instead of range or rangeBands.